# LVMCache: Why use a cachepool instead of a cachevol?

Tags: lvm, hard-disk, ssd, cache, bcache

I'm aware of the differences between a `cachepool` and `cachevol`.

`Cachepool` separates the cache data and metadata into two separate volumes, whereas a `Cachevol` uses a single volume for both.

My question is, what is the benefit of using a `cachepool` instead of just using a `cachevol`? The only scenario I can think of that it would make the most sense would be if you wanted to dedicate a single device (or single set of devices) to the cache's metadata, and a separate device (or set of devices) for the actual cache data. But that seems like a very specific scenario, and it also doesn't address the question of `Why?`

Why do most people default to using a `cachepool` instead of a `cachevol`, esp. when one device is used for caching?

What is the motivation/pros-cons to using a `cachepool` vs `cachevol`?

**EDIT** For context, the motivation behind this question comes from an assumption that `cachepool` is used in conservative setups (like home servers and desktops) simply because the guides and tutorials that people follow have trickled down from Enterprise use-cases.

Outside of tooling support, and based solely on the merits of `cachepool` vs `cachevol`, is there any concrete reason (performance, implementation, etc...) that motivates people to advocate for `cachepool` instead? Or is it simply a victim of an Enterprise trickle-down phenomenon?

If the latter is true, it may justify more conservative setups considering `cachevol` instead of `cachepool` if they don't need the flexibility and complexity of a `cachepool` setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my limited perspective, there really isn't a reason for everyone to be using a `cachepool`, and it's the result of blindly following enterprise tutorials for the sake of it.

Outside of using a separate physical drive for metadata and a separate physical drive for data, for the sake of improving throughput, I can't find much justification for using a `cachepool`. If you're only using a single SSD for caching (which, I would assume is the vast majority of desktop users), it seems that a `cachevol` is more than sufficient.

And, it potentially maximizes your caching ability. Rather than having a reduced cache size for data in order to allow room for the metadata, you can leave that up to LVM and allocate the entire device as a `cachevol`.

It seems like the only reason for a `cachepool` is for caching using two or more SSDs.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete reason to use a cachepool instead of a cachevol, is that, as of early 2024, the maintenance tools for dm-cache do not understand cachevols. `lvconvert --repair` on a damaged cachevol will print a bizarre error message about not knowing what to do with a "linear" LV, and the lower-level programs from [thin-provisioning-tools](https://github.com/jthornber/thin-provisioning-tools) insist on being given separate data and metadata devices.

Comment: Third-party tools like `thin-provisioning-tools` are typically built to target the most common use cases. My question is specifically related to the technology and the implementation. My assumption is that the reason why `cachepool` is used more often than `cachevol` is simply because it is more applicable to enterprise use-cases, and that's why most tutorials and guides steer their users in that direction; And that, realistically, it's likely that `cachevol` was just created as a convenience tool, potentially for more conservative applications (like home use) that no one really uses.

Comment: There isn't really any out there advocating for `cachevol` over `cachepool` on its merits. My question is "why?", very specifically based on the merits of `cachevol` over `cachepool`. It very well could be the victim of the same phenomenon that produces third-party tools that don't really support `cachevol`: Enterprises primarily used it, and so people with more conservative uses have just adopted those enterprise solutions in their home setups, and no one has really questioned it.

Comment: @Swivel The `thin-provisioning-tools` are the official maintenance tools developed by the same people who wrote dm-cache. The lvm utilities just call them. The fact that there is currently _no way_ to repair a damaged cachevol is exactly what you were looking for, IMHO: a concrete reason to prefer a cachepool over a cachevol, for any use.